# Corresponding Dictionary Keys and Values Outputs

Tags: python, dictionary

As a dictionary is not ordered the output is also not ordered:

```
>>> d = dict(b = 1, a = 2, z = 3)
>>> d.keys()
['a', 'z', 'b']
>>> d.values()
[2, 3, 1]
```

But are the `keys` and `values` outputs above always in corresponding order?

Comment: Note, (pedantic point) dictionaries are ordered in CPython 3.6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-cpython-3-6

Comment: @Chris_Rands I read that and it looks like it is not clear if that should be relied upon.

Comment: @ayhan The text and sample here are clearer than in the other question.

Comment: I don't agree. The title itself explains the issue. If you think it would improve with a clearer example you can always edit it but I don't think it is a good enough reason to close that canonical question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @ayhan It is not necessary to be one and not the other. It can be both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes.

From [python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the creation of (value, key) pairs using zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys()). The same relationship holds for the iterkeys() and itervalues() methods: pairs = zip(d.itervalues(), d.iterkeys()) provides the same value for pairs. Another way to create the same list is pairs = [(v, k) for (k, v) in d.iteritems()].

And from [python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

> If keys, values and items views are iterated over with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the order of items will directly correspond